# Is Google's V8 JavaScript engine available for iOS?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, v8

Can I use V8 on iOS? If not, which embeddable JavaScript engine do you recommend?

**EDIT:**

We don't plan on using it in conjunction with HTML rendering, just for internal scripting.

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317776/embed-javascript-engine-in-ios-application

Comment: There's a somewhat recent (2013 August) effort to adapt the V8 source to iOS: https://github.com/nguyenduong/V8-iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple requires that you use WebKit when rendering web-content in an app, and they may reject your app if you use something else.

That said, you may want JavaScript for something other than rendering a webpage, and in theory that use-case should allow you to use whatever JavaScript engine you want.  As the V8 source-code is available in C++, it should be possible to compile it into an iOS project.  To do so you'll need to rename any `.m` files that make use of V8 functionality (either directly or indirectly through transitive dependencies) to `.mm` so that XCode knows to compile those files as Objective-C++.

This process of getting it to work will likely be a bit finicky, but in theory it should be possible.

Comment: V8 is c++ **and an assembler**.  C++ is fairly portable, the assembler and code generation are *very* architecture specific.  To me that is the biggest question about V8 on the iOS platform.