# JavaScript with Objective-C to parse data from the web

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c

I was wondering if I can use JavaScript with Objective-C to parse data.
I saw examples of getting `NSMutableData` from a web server.

I was wondering if I could then use JavaScript methods for parsing the data in the DOM tree (ie `getElementById`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but you can definitely use JavaScript with Objective-C. On iOS, you could put the `NSData` that you got from a server into a `UIWebView` with the `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` method. Then you can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to run any JavaScript on the stuff you put into the web view.

There's a second option. You could use JavaScriptCore directly, but I don't think that's what you're looking for: [Embed a JavaScript engine in an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317776/embed-javascript-engine-in-ios-application/6592381#6592381)

Comment: Yeah I was trying to see if I could get the data from the web server (like view source), search for certain tags using Javascript, like getElementById.value, and then show my values in a nice UITableView or something like that.