# How to configure NSRegularExpression to be compatible with ECMA-262

Tags: objective-c, regex, ecma262

I need to be ECMA-262 regex compliant and NSRegularExpression is ICU regex compliant. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines), there are a few difference between the two. - are there any `NSRegularExpression` `NSMatchingOptions` or  options I can pass to make NSRegularExpression ECMA-262 compliant (or at least closer to compliant)?

Code:

```
NSError * error;
NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString options:0 error:&error];
if (!error && [regex firstMatchInString:keyString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, keyString.length)]) {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: There is no such option, as far as I can see in the documentation. And by the way, ICU regex is closer to Java's flavor than ECMA-262 flavor.

Comment: thanks nhahtdh. I need to get as close as poss to the ECMA flavor. One big difference I notices was that ICU as the look-behind capability. I wonder if I could at least turn this off...

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317776/embed-a-javascript-engine-in-an-ios-application and this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the documentation on [the syntax of ICU regular expression](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) doesn't seem to contain anything that makes the engine compatible with ECMA-262 RegExp.

Going in the direction of using a JavaScript engine to evaluate a RegExp match compliant to ECMA-262 specs:

- Load a [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and make use of the method:

  ```
  - (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
  ```

  It is said to be slow by the author of this question [Embed a JavaScript engine in an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317776/embed-a-javascript-engine-in-an-ios-application)
- Use [JavaScriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref/_index.html) framework. Check `JSContextRef.h`, then `JSBase.h` to find out what you need to get it working.

  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317776/embed-a-javascript-engine-in-an-ios-application/20428660#20428660) from the same question also refers to videos of WWDC 2013 presentation, which introduces JavaScriptCore framework.
- Also mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317776/embed-a-javascript-engine-in-an-ios-application/6592381#6592381) from the same question, you may build and ship a JavaScript engine with your app.